# Problem in my jumping Script with characheter controller unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I was testing my scripts and i wanted my player to jump with character controller and i am having a problem with it.
[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9OjM.png)

```

```
public CharacterController control;

public float playerSpeed;
public float jumpSpeed;

void Start()
{
    playerSpeed = 6.0f;
    jumpSpeed = 50;
}

void Update()
{       

    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    Vector3 move = new Vector3 (h, 0, v);
    Vector3 velocity = move * playerSpeed;

    if (control.isGrounded && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        velocity.y += jumpSpeed; // velocity.y = jumpSpeed; tried both
    }
    else
    {
        velocity += Physics.gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    }
        control.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

}```

Here's my unity screen and code above.

The problem is when i press jump it does jump but it's position goes to 2.068, i.e it jumps to low and when gravity is activated it comes down to slow, it takes around 6 seconds to come to its initial position.

I even tried to add a parent object to it so that it may change, but it does the same to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (control.isGrounded && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
{
    // first just try this
    velocity.y += jumpSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
}
else
{
    velocity.y -= Physics.gravity * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

and if it is not working

```
Vector3 move = new Vector3 (h, 0, 0);
Vector3 jump = new Vector3 (0, 0, v);
Vector3 _velocityMove = move * playerSpeed;
Vector3 _velocityJump = jump* jumpSpeed;

 if (control.isGrounded && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
{
    velocity.y += _velocityJump ;//and you can add ' * Time.deltaTime '
}
else
{
    velocity += Physics.gravity * Time.deltaTime;
}
    control.Move(_velocityMove * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: if we add the first code, it doesnt even jump as it is constantly increasing and at the same time decreasing with Time.

Comment: in the second code you wrote _velocityMove in the Move function which doesnt even make the player move in z axis. and by modifying it, it function exactly the same as my previous code.

Answer (score 0):

ohk so I tweaked some of my code and instead of declaring velocity.y in the condition of if the player is grounded , i declared outside the condition and change the value of variable in condition.

```
velocity.y = jumpSpeed;

if (control.isGrounded && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
{
    jumpSpeed = 10;
}
else
{
    jumpSpeed += Physics.gravity.y * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

This seems to do the trick and my player can jump nicely.